# Paperclip File Upload - Store file outside of public

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :photo,
  :path => "#{Rails.root}/system/:class/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "#{Rails.root}/system/:class/:id/:style/:filename",
```

I would like to store my images outside of the public directory in a directory called system.  The file gets saved properly, however the image does not display as it should.  Instead of showing the image, it outputs the filename in text minus the .jpg.

The server log says:

```
 No route matches [GET] "/.../system/images/10/small/cessna-a-803.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Path should be like

```
:path => "#{Rails.root}/system/:class/:id/:style/:style.:extension",
```

Comment: That saves the file name as thefilename.jpg.jpg.  The image still does not get rendered in the view.

Comment: The save location and file name is described by :path.

Comment: has_attached_file :photo,
  :path => "#{Rails.root}/system/:class/:id/:style/:filename.:extension",
  :url => "#{Rails.root}/system/:class/:id/:style/:filename",

Comment: That saves the file as filename.jpg.jpg  The view then renders the name of the filename in plain text.  Log says: No route matches [GET] "/.../system/images/11/small/filename.jpg"

Comment: try to change :path => "#{Rails.root}/system/:class/:id/:style/:style.:extension"